# Blazor - Refresh child component on its parameter change

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor page that uses my custom `ExamTicketDisplay` component with `TicketId` parameter like this
`<ExamTicketDisplay TicketId="@_currentTicket"/>`

As `_currentTicket`'s value changes I expect `ExamTicketDisplay` to be re-rendered with its new parameter value, but that does not happen. The component does not re-render with new value, `OnInitializedAsync` method is not called even if parent's `StateHasChanged()` is called.

How can I make this child component to re-render when the parameter changes?

I tried to call `OnInitializedAsync` method manually in parameter's set method, but that looks like a crunch for me

```
[Required]
[Parameter]
public int TicketId
{
    get => _ticketId;
    set
    {
        _ticketId = value;
        OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the context you're using it I don't think `[Required]` does anything (unless you have some custom code to detect it).  It's an `int`, so will always have a value - the default is 0.  I think what you're looking for is `[Parameter, EditorRequired]` which will throw a warning in your dev environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to manually call `OnInitializedAsync` like that. For this you need to use [`OnParametersSetAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#after-parameters-are-set-onparameterssetasync) lifecycle method.

```cs
[Required]
[Parameter]
public int TicketId { get; set; }

private int _currentTicketId;

protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    if (_currentTicketId != TicketId)
    {
        _currentTicketId = TicketId;
        // ticket id has changed, do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah OP, don't call lifecycle methods explicitly.

Comment: Many thanks! Didn't know that blazor doesn't create new instance of the component upon re-rendering (the reason why I expected OnInitializedAsync method to be invoked).